# How to solve this Android Project dependency issue?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dependencies, project

I have the following projects under Eclipse:

**A (Android Project) => B (Java Project) => C (Java Project)**

where symbol "=>" indicates that the project to the left of the symbol is dependent on the project to the right of the symbol and the **build path of project B always include project C** under all circumstances.

If I include both project B and C under the build path of project A, A runs without problems.

However, **if I include project B without including project C under the build path of project A, A crashes when run.**

**Is there an alternative to solving the above issue without including project C under the build path of project A** since there is no direct dependency between A and C?

Note that C should not be converted to an android project so as to allow other java projects (not indicated here) that depend on it to run as well.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't solve the base problem although there are a lot of workarounds.

Everything has to be included otherwise you will get classnotfound exceptions. You can always build Project C to a JAR file and include that in your lib path and then you won't have to have the dependency on the project. Build Project B to, to a Jar file and you can develop your android project without any references to any eclipse Java projects.

Think of it this way if you download a jar file for example Farmors super lib far.jar and my lib have other dependencies you have to fetch them to and there dependencies and so on recursively thats why we have advance tools like maven to handle all this dependance mess.

Answer (score 0):

Librairy from project C should be exported by project B.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=367962 
section 6.1.4

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: I have tried exporting project C from project B but the same issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution in your case is to move your project to use tools like **maven** or **ivy**. Those kind of tools helps you to manage this kind of problems that are dependency management. Of course, those tools provide many more features, for example, improving the process of build, filtering resources, deploying automatically artifacts, create reports, etc

I work with maven a lot and I try to explain how I try to solve the problem in your case. First of all, you could mavenize all of our projects (including the Android one) and define the relationship between your projects (**A** depends on **B**, who depends on **C**), only, setting the most important project for maven projects, the 'pom.xml' file.

In [this link][3] you could read about *Introduction to dependency mechanism*. The idea is simple: you need to define the organization of what requires every project, that can be artifacts or libraries around the net. Maven will download everything and will build every project. In your case, probably you will need to build the C project, that automatically (once it is configured correctly) would be used by the B project, and so on by A.

Pay attention to understand how dependencies are managed, because it's the key.

By the way, in the Android project probably you will need to use the [Android maven plugin][4] that will fit perfectly for your purposes.

Good luck!